# How does one set up JavaDoc DocCheck as an Eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I have recently started using DocCheck for checking the validity of JavaDoc's in code files.

Is there some way to set DocCheck up as an eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was deemed a great idea [back in 2002](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools/msg22613.html), and still [asked for in 2004](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.jdt/msg13001.html)...

But since then, pretty much all the features of the [Sun Doc Check Doclet](http://java.sun.com/j2se/javadoc/doccheck/docs/index.html) (experimental code developed originally for internal use at Sun and released to the developer community for use as-is) is pretty much covered by the '`Java Compiler / Javadoc`' section of the Java project properties (albeit without the HTML rapports outputs)

If you do want to have the DocCheck reports, I would recommend making a [**custom Project Builder**](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Builders/builders.html), like [this one](http://www.bell-labs.com/project/nmake/manual/eclipsejdt.html) (not related to DocCheck at all, just here to give you an example)

[image]
<sub>(source: [bell-labs.com](http://www.bell-labs.com/project/nmake/manual/eclipse/jdt_lu38/builders.png))</sub>

See also **[FAQ How do I implement an incremental project builder?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_implement_an_incremental_project_builder%3F)** or **[FAQ How do I create an external tool builder?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_external_tool_builder%3F)**

I would also recommend you set up this custom builder calling DocCheck only when doing a fill build (`IncrementalProjectBuilder.FULL_BUILD`), in order to avoid to wait each time you save a file.

> End users can add external tool builders by selecting a project in the Navigator, choosing Properties, and then going to the **Builders page**.
>   On the Build Options tab, you can specify whether the builder should run on autobuild, manual build, or on **Clean**.
>   In most cases, running external tool builders during auto-builds is too disruptive because they are too long running.