# Eclipse javadoc coverage plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

i want to find out what classes need some javadoc love in my project. Is there a plugin for eclipse (or a standalone app) that would tell me what methods don't have a javadoc yet and perhaps even tells me if some are wrong (parameters changed etc).

This is more or less the last plugin i need to create great code :D thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are specifically after a Javadoc quality tool, then **[Sun's Doc Check Doclet](http://java.sun.com/j2se/javadoc/doccheck/index.html)** has this covered.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073531/how-does-one-set-up-javadoc-doccheck-as-an-eclipse-plugin) for hints on how to integrate it with eclipse.

---

+1 for CheckStyle - great tool for code quality in general

Answer (score 4):

Give [CheckStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/index.html) a shot.

It will do all that and more.  In particular, it will [check for well-formed Javadoc comments on methods, params, packages, variables](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html#JavadocMethod).  It will flag them as you code, much like Eclipse does already with compilation errors.

It's really a great tool.  Available as a plugin, ant task, or standalone.